# Liberty - Messages.log / Console.log / trace.log not getting rotated on server

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

We have specified the below configuration on server and we see that logs are not getting rotated as expected, Can you please suggest how can we control on Liberty to make sure we can rotate the messages.log, Console.log and trace.log with 20 max files and 20 MB each.

```
<logging traceSpecification="*=audit=enabled:com.worklight.*=info=enabled"  traceFileName="trace.log" maxFileSize="20"  maxFiles="20" traceFormat="BASIC" />
```

we understand the above specification is meant only for controlling trace.log. But we see in our logs the below behaviour, CAn you please guide us to know from where messages.log and console.log are getting rotated at first place.

```
1**1 Aug 19 15:41 *console_14.08.19_15.36.03.0.log*
2**0 Sep 05 13:40 *trace_14.09.05_13.42.33.0.log*
8**88 Sep 05 14:52 *trace.log*
1**94 Oct 13 15:40 *messages_14.10.13_15.41.09.0.log*
20480 Nov 15 23:06 ffdc
20*****3 Nov 27 13:57 *messages_14.11.27_14.02.38.0.log*
11****7 Dec 16 15:35 *messages.log*
24****1 Dec 16 15:35 *console.log*
```

Comment: I think you meant to include your server configuration here, but it is not present in the question.  Can you update the question to include your server.xml file, or provide a link where it can be viewed?

Comment: It was there, just not properly formatted. Fixed.

Comment: @djrecker, is this in the development environment or in a production environment? where are you applying this?

Comment: The WAS docs: http://ibm.co/1wCHijf mention that this does not apply to console.log, but I am not sure why this is not working for all the other files you've mentioned... I do think is not worklight related at all as this is a WAS/Liberty feature - even the logs belong to that application server, not to Worklight.

Comment: This is a Production environment, What we understand from the above trace specification is only meant for controlling trace.log, How can we control or rotate the messages.log, console.log as well. Please suggest, Also to add we are able to see the below messages.log getting archived , Can you please help us know from where could this possible been set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per link provided by @Idan [Liberty profile: Logging and Trace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.iseries.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F2-16-0-0&lang=en):

`console.log` is not being rotated:

> The `console.log` file does not have the same level of management as
>   other log files. The only property that you can change is
>   `consoleLogLevel`. If you are concerned about the increasing size of the
>   console.log file, you can disable the `console.log` file and use the
>   message log file instead.

Rotation is for `messages.log` and `trace.log`. In addition to rotating based on the file size, new files are created after each server restart, and the `console.log` is reset on restart.